# Загрузка фото VK API. Java

Tags: java, android, вконтакте, api

Работаю в Android Studio. С помощью моей программы можно опубликовать пост в сообществе ВК. Авторизацию сделал. Далее Нужно загрузить фото на сервер, но при попытке сделать это, в консоли я наблюдаю ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот кусок кода, где я произвожу действия:

```
ImageView imgVkPost = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgVkPost);

final Bitmap photo =((BitmapDrawable) imgVkPost.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
VKRequest request2 = VKApi.uploadWallPhotoRequest(new VKUploadImage(photo, VKImageParameters.jpgImage(0.9f)), 0, 60479154);

request2.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        super.onComplete(response);

        System.out.println(response.json.toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(VKError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибочка вышла:(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println(error);
    }
    @Override
    public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) {

    }
});
```

Как быть? Что делаю не так?

Comment: в методе логина вк вы параметром передали доступ к заливу фото?

Comment: Ойойой. Точно)) Сначала подумал, что это не будет иметь значение, так как id стоит 0, но решил попробовать передать scope - photos. И о да, робит! Спасибо огромное, что открыли мне глаза:)

Comment: @ВикторШамрук, вы можете написать это в ответ - это может быть полезным для будущих посетителей этого вопроса, которые сюда из поисковиков придут)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Access denied: no access to call this method

. Ошибка возникает, если при логине через метод

`VKSdk.login(context, VKScope permissionParams...);`

вы не передали пермишны на соответсвующую операцию. в Вашем случае это пермишны на залив фото.

P.S. Мой комментарий оформленный в виде ответа